# Cardview side by side in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, cardview

Trying to produce a Xamarin.Forms page across all devices (iOS, Android, UWP) but need the contents to be displayed as card views side-by-side like the example below.

What is the best way to achieve this? Is there any OSS library out there since I can't seem to find anything like this out-of-the-box?

[image: card view listing]

EDIT: Unfortunately I forgot to mention that this is to be bindable to an Ienumerable source. Number of items is not fixed. Contents inside each card will have the same template only from different items.

Thanks

Comment: Do you want it to act as a listview or fixed layout?

Comment: If possible I would like the number of columns to be dynamic depending on the width of the screen.

Comment: I ll post an answer below and i hope it helps u.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Things have moved on since the question was first asked. You can now use a CollectionView with a GridItemsLayout with a span of 2 to achieve the layout required.: [Link to Xamarin Forms CollectionView documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/layout)

Answer (score 0):

So as i understood from your comments what u need to do is a Grid within a ScrollView. Here is an exmaple;

```
 <ScrollView Orientation="Vertical">
    <Grid RowSpacing="10" ColumnSpacing="10">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="AUTO"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="AUTO"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Frame Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">
            <!--DO YOUR DESIGN FOR FRAME No. 1 HERE-->
        </Frame>
            <Frame Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0">
                <!--DO YOUR DESIGN FOR FRAME No. 2 HERE-->
            </Frame>
            <Frame Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0">
                <!--DO YOUR DESIGN FOR FRAME No. 3 HERE-->
            </Frame>
            <Frame Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0">
                <!--DO YOUR DESIGN FOR FRAME No. 4 HERE-->
            </Frame>
            <Frame Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1">
                <!--DO YOUR DESIGN FOR FRAME No. 5 HERE-->
            </Frame>
            <Frame Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1">
                <!--DO YOUR DESIGN FOR FRAME No. 6 HERE-->
            </Frame>
            <Frame Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1">
                <!--DO YOUR DESIGN FOR FRAME No. 7 HERE-->
            </Frame>
            <Frame Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1">
                <!--DO YOUR DESIGN FOR FRAME No. 8 HERE-->
            </Frame>
        </Grid>
    </ScrollView>
```

What i would truly suggest though is to search for a library that would give you the possibility to do it in ListView. This way you will reduce your hardcoded design code and obtain better and easier access to your layout.

Comment: Hi @Andreas, thanks for your help. Static layout is not what I wanted. The number of items is to be based on a bindable Ienumerable property from the view model. My mistake on the explanation. Sorry

Comment: No problem! i made something like this before. If you still havent found an answer please tell me so I can search for it in my archive.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following library which is a ListView derivative with flowing, grid-like columns support.

https://github.com/daniel-luberda/DLToolkit.Forms.Controls